# Can I do this in fetching a data an increasing it by 1?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I fetched a data from a database table. It is an integer value. Now I want to increase it by 1 and send it to another table. Can this be done to increase its value by 1?

```
String transaction = resultset.getString(1) + 1;
```

Comment: No why not `Integer transaction = resultSet.getInt(1) + 1;` then call the update query. because when you concatenate a String with an Integer it will not return the sum but the concatenation for example `String s = "123"; s = s + 1;` the result of s is `1231`

Comment: why don`t you convert string to int and do the operation. Then you could convert it to string

Answer (score 2):

I would actually recommend just doing a single insert or update operation.  For example, if you wanted to *insert* this value into a new record in another table you could try:

```
INSERT INTO other_table (col)
SELECT id + 1
FROM first_table;
```

This would only require a single trip to the database, rather than making two trips, via a separate select and DML statements.

This answer is a bit thin on Java code, but for boilerplate JDBC code, you should refer to Java Trails or another SO question.

Comment: Didn't you miss the `VALUES` keyword?

Comment: @Lino No, I didn't miss it.  `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` is a perfectly valid construct on almost all SQL databases.  `VALUES` is mainly used for inserting _constants_.  But, here we're not interested in a constant, but rather some column value.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, sorry for the confusion then. Learned something new today :)

Comment: the value from the column i am fetching is autogenerated and on the other hand i am sending this data along with other data to the other table.

Comment: i doing this in jsp

Comment: @MayukhSinghaRoy OK...auto generated doesn't change much so long as that value already exists when you are going to select it.  So, does that record already exist?